# find -exec basename {} vs find -exec echo $(basename {})

Tags: bash

I'm sure I'm missing something but I can't figure it out. Given:

```
$ find -type f
./hello.txt
./wow.txt
./yay.txt
```

how come the next two commands render different results?

```
$ find -type f -exec basename {} \;
hello.txt
wow.txt
yay.txt

$ find -type f -exec echo $(basename {}) \;
./hello.txt
./wow.txt
./yay.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

`$(basename {})` is evaluated **before** the command runs.

The result is `{}` so the command `echo $(basename {})` becomes `echo {}` and `basename` is not run for each file.

Answer (score 2):

A quick debug on that using the `bash -x` debugger demonstrated this,

[*The example is my own, just for demonstration purposes*]

```
bash -xc 'find -type f -name "*.sh" -exec echo $(basename {}) \;'
++ basename '{}'
+ find -type f -name '*.sh' -exec echo '{}' ';'
./1.sh
./abcd/another_file_1_not_ok.sh
./abcd/another_file_2_not_ok.sh
./abcd/another_file_3_not_ok.sh
```

And for just `basename {}`

```
bash -xc 'find -type f -name "*.sh" -exec basename {} \;'
+ find -type f -name '*.sh' -exec basename '{}' ';'
1.sh
another_file_1_not_ok.sh
another_file_2_not_ok.sh
another_file_3_not_ok.sh
```

As you can see in the first example, `echo $(basename {})` gets resolved in two steps, `basename {}` is nothing but the `basename` on the actual file (which outputs the plain file name) which is then interpreted as `echo {}`. So it is nothing but mimic-ing the exact behaviour when you use `find` with `exec` and `echo` the files as

```
bash -xc 'find -type f -name "*.sh" -exec echo {} \;'
+ find -type f -name '*.sh' -exec echo '{}' ';'
./1.sh
./abcd/another_file_1_not_ok.sh
./abcd/another_file_2_not_ok.sh
./abcd/another_file_3_not_ok.sh
```